# How to find out what JavaScript function triggered HTML change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebug

I am having a problem on a WordPress site. I have a function which slides down a certain `<div>`. It is:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(document).on('click','.tb_usertask_title',function(){
        var title = $(this);
        var key = title.data('key');
        var msg = $('#tb_msg_'+key);
        msg.slideDown('fast');
    }
});
```

After executing this function, the `<div>` slides up again immediately. I think this might be due another script, but I have absolutely no idea how to find which function does this. Is there any way of finding this out? Things I have tried:

- Adding breakpoints in my function. This showed me that the folding up happened outside my function.
- Using Firebug to break on HTML change. This however redirected to jquery.js, but I did not know how to find out which function triggered the jQuery.
- Using Firebug to list the events of my `onclick` event, but this only showed my function.

These didn't work for me. I also searched for a way to do a function backtrace in Firebug, but without any success.

Comment: are you using bootstrap too?

Comment: no (15 character minimum)

Comment: For testing purpose, is it same behaviour if you bind click event to element and stop propagation? `$('.tb_usertask_title').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    //...
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use unminified version of jQuery (just for the test and because its more easy to debug).
2. Look for the dispatch function.
3. Put a breakpoint in the function where there is an apply usage.
4. After the code breaks use the F11 to navigate to the binding function.

[image]